# Array property display format in WinForms Property Grid

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

I have an object with a string[] property. When I assign this as the SelectedObject in the PropertyGrid, I get a "String[] Array" displayed for that property.

Is there a way I can change this display part to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it's currently displaying the ToString() value; so one option is to override the ToString() method to display a formatted string--if a string is what you want.

---

A little Google work turned up [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) from our very own admin Mr. Marc Gravell from another place and time.  His answer is pretty solid

Comment: That link goes to a top level of a blog that does not address this problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It displays "String[] Array" because you need to provide a type converter for that property.
Here is the link with detailed solution: [How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).